# create-react-app webapp - ReferenceError: Can't find variable 'Map' - on iOS 7/Safari

Tags: reactjs, polyfills

I tried running my react web app on an old iPhone 4 (running iOS 7). Even though I added "iOS 7" to the browserslist in package.json, the app still won't run.

Debugging shows me there is an error in `1.chunk.js`

```
Can't find variable 'Map'
```

Adding erroneous code to App.js at the top, or to `index.js` leads me to believe this chunk is run before any of my code. So I don't think I can fix it by importing a polyfill in those files.

I've tried adding a polyfill script for Map in the index.html, which got me to the next error

```
Can't find variable 'Set'
```

But hacking things this way isn't a good solution.

For now, I've ejected `npm run eject` create-react-app, which I'd rather not do, but it may allow me to trick `webpack` into adding polyfills before that 1.chunk.js code.

Is there a good way to not eject create-react-app, and get the polyfills in place without hacks in the index.html?

Edit: Just using an already bundled core-js bundle in the head of the page solved all my issues. The CDN bundle can be used like this:

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.0.1"></script>
```

Or this, if you want to use the minified version:

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.0.1/minified.js"></script>
```

Not marking it as solved, since there may be a proper solution too. However, including any polyfills in your own code will never be picked up by the build scripts to 'fix' the third-party that is run before your code.

Comment: are you using react or react-native ?

Comment: react, not react-native. It's just a webpage. I've updated the question and title to make this more clear.